# how to check a date is less than today date in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

my collection in db is

```
plannedEndDate:{"2020-03-10T11:22:33.677+00:00"}
```

in controller `var tdate= new Date();` [tdate is in the format 2020-03-10T14:28:22.687Z].
 now,I need to check plannedEndDate is less than tdate in mongoose.
i tried,

```
plannedEndCmp: {
    $cond: [{ $lt: ["$plannedEndDate", tdate] }, 1, 0]
}
```

but it is not returning true.
so should i need to trim the timestamp to compare dates in mangodb?or should i need to convert date into common format?

Comment: Is  `"2020-03-10T11:22:33.677+00:00"` stored as **string** or is it a proper `Date` (resp. `ISODate`) object?

Comment: You compare `createddate` with `plannedEndDate`!

Comment: Hello.It is stored as proper Date object.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you actually like to do but below command find the document or show indication:

```
db.collection.find(
   { plannedEndDate: { $lt: tdate } }
)

db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { plannedEndCmp: { $cond: [{ $lt: ["$plannedEndDate", tdate] }, 1, 0] } } },
   { $set: { plannedEndCmp_bool: { $lt: ["$plannedEndDate", tdate] } } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Aggregate group:
`

```
factualEndDate: {
          "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$factualEndDate" }
        },
```

In Aggregate  project:

`DelayedComplete: {  $cond: [`

```
        {
          $and: [

            { $cond: [{ $lte: [{ $max: "$data.factualEndDate" }, today] }, 1, 0] },


          ]
        },
        1,
        0
      ]
    },
```

`